# Parsing AS3 XML objects

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I am getting an object back from ASP.NET, and when tracing the XML it as follows:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(event.message.body);
trace(xml);
```

I get the following output:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://localhost:49329/">
    <string>One</string>
    <string>Two</string>
    <string>Three</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I am trying to iterate the structure to get the strings extracted, but to no avail. I am using the following code:

```
for each(var item:Object in xml.children())
{
    MonsterDebugger.trace(this, item.toString());
}
```

...and I know this is not entirely effective. It works now, but there is a way to get the strings with some syntax using the @ sign.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Does this have something to do with the namespace? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://localhost:49329/">
    <string>One</string>
    <string>Two</string>
    <string>Three</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

You have to take care of the Namespace too:

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://localhost:49329/");
var strings:XMLList = xml.ns::string;
for each(var str:XML in strings)
  trace(str.text());
```

Comment: just 2 hours? I've wasted more than a day pulling my hair over namespaces ;)

Answer (score 2):

You've pretty much got it. Should be able to write the same loop like so:

```
for each( var el:XML in xml.string ) {
  trace( el.toString() );
}
```

Take a look at these [e4x docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_01.html), these are for Flex, but it all applies because it's just AS3. As you can see the state of documentation on a lot of this stuff is a little flaky :)

Comment: That's exactly what's confusing me so much today, when I try this way, like I did most of today, I just get nothing at all?

Comment: Ah, yea. Missed the namespace in the `ArrayOfString` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read my answer to [AS3 - Deepest XML Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687603/as3-deepest-xml-elements/5300700#5300700)
By using SimpleXML you can parse your XML in an easy to use manner.